# Will a development process that doesn't emphasize automated unit tests get worse with Scrum?

Tags: unit-testing, agile, scrum

I work in a development group with perhaps 120 developers, with smaller divisions within that.  Our process is somewhere between waterfall and agile, more towards the former.  We do NOT have our builds executing unit tests and there is only casual use of them in the various teams.  Nothing resembling TDD happens here.

We've been going through Scrum training, and are trying to use agile methods for some projects, and move others towards agile in the future.

I've been concerned about our de-emphasis of automated unit tests for quite a while.  During this Scrum/Agile training process, I've tried to make the point that the lack of automated unit tests in our builds could be a problem, even more so with agile processes, specifically using short iterations.  The response to this from the "movers and shakers" is that this is an XP topic, and we're implementing Scrum.

Assuming you agree with my concerns, what arguments could I present to the people who pay the bills that the development of a good automated unit test infrastructure (and understanding) needs to have higher priority?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best argument I've seen used is ***it is cheaper to fix bugs early***.

In particular, as you say, with short iterations untested code will almost certainly fail when deployed. Having the team stop to perform manual testing, then fixes, ***introduces uncertainty into the schedule*** when ideally the best practice of Scrum is that a well-defined rhythm of frequent high quality releases is what's needed.

It can also be difficult to integrate untested code across a larger team: even the best written specifications can be ambiguous, and are frequently worse. Having a good robust test suite ***is a great specification for what the code actually does***.

Once the code has been written, decent test coverage lets you take code and ***change it knowing that it still works as defined***. In particular the effort associated with regression testing is greatly reduced.

I've seen management try to "cut corners" in this way by suggesting that testing is done outside of the core development function and away from the sprint cycle. In my experience that ends in tears, with the software delivered later than if proper effort was made to find and fix the bugs early.

Perhaps it's a cultural issue, but in the UK the best practice I've seen for Scrum etc. is to not get too concerned with whether a particular part of the process is XP, Agile, Scrum or what-have-you. Rather, a policy of *inspect and adapt* suggests that a team can themselves decide to improve their code through adopting a particular policy; then, if after a spike it appears to work, the policy is adopted more widely. Or not.

So, you may find it best to bide your time, then suggest improving test coverage at your next retrospective. Or, perhaps just implement them yourself... and watch your velocity improve!

Comment: This is a great answer.  I'd only add that unit tests give you confidence to change code, which is a huge plus.  It will be hard regardless of methodology if you don't have unit tests that prove code works as intended.  Tests are an upfront investment that pay off later.  The time that it takes to write the code is insignificant compared to the length of time you'll be maintaining that code.

Comment: All good points.  I laugh at your mention of "improving test coverage".  Code coverage is one of those "if I should live so long" topics here.  Concerning the idea of just "do it myself", I believe it's the case that when developers "do it on their own", they appear to take longer to get things done, compared to the developers who just get it basically working, without writing unit tests.

Comment: @Andy - most beancounters _hate_ the idea that code can change! But yes, I'll update my answer.

Comment: That reminds me of my favorite section in "Refactoring" (Martin Fowler), where he suggests that the best way to justify refactoring/improvements time to management is to just not tell them. :)

Comment: Absolutely. Think of it as encapsulation!

Comment: @DavidM.Karr I think whether you actually take longer is up for debate.  At least take significantly longer.  First off, what are you comparing to?  Really the only way to say you're taking longer is for someone else to implement the exact same task.  Second, I've found that doing the tests makes actual implementation trivial.  Since my testing has helped me flesh out exactly what the method will and won't do, coding the actual functionality is easy and takes almost no time at all.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think moving to Scrum will make things better or worse. The core issue is not whether what process you use: if there are no automated tests, there are no tests, regardless of the process. Scrum may help make the problem more blatant though: if you deploy on a regular cadence untested code, bugs will likely be discovered earlier, and your backlog will fill in with defects that have to be fixed. At that point, your team can either continue business as usual, or decide that it's better to squash bugs earlier and ship higher-quality features by including testing in the process.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that automated testing has nothing to do with the process you're following. You can be doing classic waterfall and still get great benefits from automated tests.

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy provided a very solid answer, but let me try to augment it by putting the topic in the context of your migration from waterfall to agile. We have been successfully been using agile for two years now, though not without significant growing pains.

A key success factor in Scrum agile is to maximize the amount of work NOT done. ANY sort of manual testing (unit, functional, load, scalability, negative) is engineering capacity underutilized. It's actually much worse than that since with every incremental new feature, the amount of manual testing required to maintain a certain level of quality increases non-linearly (geometrically?) with the number of features due to expansion of the test matrix caused by feature interaction. This is why at my company we call manual testing 'technical debt'.

In Scrum, testing cycles will accelerate since every user story should meet an agreed upon Definition of Done before being accepted by the Product Owner. In any given sprint, many user stories should be done by every Scrum team. If each story requires manual testing, which it should per the DoD and lack of automation, much time is wasted.

A reasonable testing strategy will look at, among other things, where code is changing, so as not to tackle low risk, static areas. With Scrum, code refactoring is encouraged because each story is a very thin slice of functionality, and customer feedback is immediately incorporated in the backlog in the form of new/modified user stories. Thus, good Scrum programs will have their 'code freeze' much closer to their 'release date' than waterfall programs. This makes it difficult to test once and be done with it. You end up paying the technical debt interest many times over.

Jeremy's last thought pertains to how you could sell your ideas or effecting change. I find this to be very important so allow me to add a few thoughts of my own. If your management is serious about Agile, they will take Scrum teams feedback seriously. During retrospective, you could ask your teammates how they feel about modifying code that has no unit test coverage. That should elicit some feedback.

Another way, is to look for evidence of obstacles in your program artifacts. An obstacle being defined as anything that slows teams down. Do you have a bug tracking system where 'regression' defects are identified? Does your team track how often a given test case is run? Is there any component of your software that might have decent unit test coverage? If so, do teams working on it run into fewer issues than other teams? Management cares about dollars/pounds/euros. Figure out how much time is wasted by how many people due to lack of automated unit testing and convert into money. Managers can tell you what the fully loaded cost of one of your engineers is. And remind them that this waste is perpetual, until the technical debt is faced that is.